# Update Angular2 component only once after multiple onNgChange

Tags: typescript, angular2-components, angular2-changedetection

I have a component with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and multiple `@Input` properties.

When more than one property changes at the same time i have multiple calls to `ngOnChanges`.

I need to recalculate the size after all the `ngOnChanges` have finished (for that tick/digest/change detection cycle).

So instead of having

```
ngOnChanges(a) -> recalculate()
ngOnChanges(b) -> recalculate()
ngOnChanges(c) -> recalculate()
```

i want

```
ngOnChanges(a)
ngOnChanges(b)
ngOnChanges(c)
recalculate()
```

A setTimeout would probably work but i want to know how to do it properly using ng2 tools.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange}) {
   if(changes['a'] && changes['b'] && changes['c']){
     recalculate();
   }
  }
```

Comment: Of course `ngOnChanges` doesnt contain all changes at once